# FacebookAds Python SDK AppID KeyError

Tags: facebook, python-2.7, app-id

```
from facebookads import FacebookSession
from facebookads import FacebookAdsApi
from facebookads.objects import (
    AdUser,
    Campaign
)

import json
import os
import pprint

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
this_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
config_filename = os.path.join(this_dir, 'config.json')
config_file = open(config_filename)
config = json.load(config_file)
config_file.close()

### Setup session and api objects
session = FacebookSession(
    config['XXXXXXXXXXXXXX']--This is AppId,
    config['XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX']--This is AppSecret,
    config['XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX']--This is AccessToken,
)

api = FacebookAdsApi(session)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    FacebookAdsApi.set_default_api(api)

    print('\n\n\n********** Reading objects example. **********\n')
```

I try collect facebook-ads results cliks, page view etc. And this is my code part. If i run this code i have a this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kerimcaner/PycharmProjects/facebook/deneme.py", line 23, in <module>
    config[XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX],
KeyError: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I check many times my appId so its true but code is not working.

Comment: Try this first in the Graph API explorer and see if you are getting results. If so, then this might be an issue of how you are implementing/using the SDK.

Comment: Graph API explorer is not open